# Quick Conditional Probability Question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Been going through lecture notes (ones I made *myself*, so who knows how accurate they are - or rather - they most certainly are not) and can't seem to understand this one example

**Example:** Two horses - **A** and **B**. **A** wins with probability 0.5, **B** wins with probability 0.3. What is the probability that **B** wins?

The calculation that follows:
$$P(B|A^C)=\frac{P(B\cap A^C)}{P(A^C)}=\frac{0.3}{0.5}=0.6 $$

Now, I have no trouble with the theory, just understanding what is actually meant by the question. My questions:

**1)** Should the question really be "What is the probability that B wins, **given that A doesn't?**"

**2)** Is $P(B)=P(B\cap A^C)$ since $P(A\cap B)=\emptyset$ (or is that true?)

Perhaps 1) and 2) are *obviously* true and I just forgot to add that sentence in my notes. But I want to be sure (and be able to sleep at night :) )

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1, is correct.

2, $p(B)=p(A\cap  B)+p(A^c\cap B)$

Comment: Thanks. Isn't it however true, in this case, that $P(A\cap B)=\emptyset$, thus 2 would be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both observations are correct and "obvious". But what's obvious at the time (or to an expert) isn't always obvious when you're revising. Let this be a lesson to you about high quality note-taking. (Even if it makes me a massive hypocrite)

Answer (score 1):

The answers to both 1) and 2) seem to be 'yes'.  Certainly the calculation makes sense in that context.